# AngularJS no output

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've started learning AngularJS using some tutorials on youtube.
In a tutorial there's this code but when I coded it , the browser won't show the properties.
How to solve it?

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html ng-app = "myModule">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>

    </title>

    <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div>
            First Name : {{ employee.firstName }}
        </div>
        <div>
            Last Name : {{ employee.lastName }}
        </div>
        <div>
            Age : {{ employee.age }}
        </div>
        <!-- <div>
            {{message}}
        </div> -->
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my script.js file

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[]);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){

        var employee = {
            firstName : "abcd",
            lastName : "efgh",
            age : 24    
        };

        $scope.employee = employee;
    });
```

In the browser it displays like this

```
 First Name :
 Last Name :
 Age :
```

Why don't it show the property details ? I mean "abcd" as the first name and so on ?

EDIT :

Still having the same problem when I'm trying to insert an image. It workds on Codepen.io and here's the link 
http://codepen.io/speco92/pen/jAQdAv

But when I checked it on my pc (localhost)image file won't load. Other object properties loads.

Here it's included screenshots of my TestMyAngular.html , script.js and the result in the browser as well ! 
https://postimg.org/gallery/2g08oma4q/

How to solve it?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tb0oqt4m). Check your console for errors

Comment: Nothing on console. Just this JS warning.
"Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."

Comment: check whether script.js file is placed in the right folder. it should be on root

Comment: yea..  I just entered 
" $scope.message ="Hey"; " in the same script file and it displayed in browser. 
Can't figure out what's wrong with this. Anyway Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please tell how you are running your angular app?? 
are you directly opening the pages in browser??

angular application cannot be opened by the filepath on the local machine because ofcross origin domain errors. You need to use some server like http-server

Comment: I didn't knew. I was running it directly .

But after u said it I ran it on my localhost. But still the same problem :(

Comment: pls share the console errors. in your browser press f12 and check console window

Comment: This was the warning 
 "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead."

Anyway I got the problem solved. It was a fault with AngularJS library. I used the CDN and it worked.

Thank u alot for the help.

Comment: Still having the same problem when I'm trying to show an image. Can't figure out why. Can u help me to solve it if u can ?
I posted it as EDIT in the same question

Comment: I think path is not initialized and image gets loaded, so use ng-src.
 ng-src  wait until the full path to the image is resolved

try this :

<img ng-src = "{{ employee.img }}" alt ="Hello !"/>

Comment: changed it. Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working.

Given that you are starting to learn AngularJS you may not know that you cannot simply double-click on your `index.html` to see the results.

If your default browser is Google Chrome, it will not work because google chrome does not allow javascripts to be run from file system.

You can open your `index.html` with Firefox for example.

If you still want to use Google Chrome your should use a webserver